# Need to ask user if he wants to try again (Python)

Tags: python

```
#Ask the user what option he wants        
mode = input("Would you like to count Vowel's or Consonant's ? (Vowel or Consonant): ")
mode = mode.strip()
mode = mode.lower()

# Tell the user the input he entered wasn't valid        
while mode != 'consonant' and mode != 'vowel':
        mode = input("That's not correct. Would you like to count Vowel's or Consonant's ? (Vowel or Consonant): ")
#get the word from the user
word = input("Please enter your Word: ")
vowel_count = 0
consonant_count = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        vowel_count += 1

for letter in word:
    if letter in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ':
        consonant_count += 1

if mode == "consonant":
        print(word,"contains", consonant_count, "consonant's")

if mode == "vowel":
        print(word,"contains", vowel_count, "vowel's")
```

1. Program Starts and asks the user whether they want to count vowels or consonants, this is stored as a "mode".  If user provides input other than "consonant" or "vowel", program interprets this as an error and re-asks for input.
2. Program asks for a word.
3. Depending on mode, number of consonants or vowels are calculated and reported to the user.
4. Program asks if another word is available.  If so, steps 2 through 4 are repeated, otherwise continue to step 5.
5. Depending on mode, average vowels per word or average consonants per word are reported to the user.

Im stuck on step 4 i don't know how to ask the other for another word and repeat the same process

Comment: Homework? Have you studied loops? Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: `@Famouskid7` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, if this is homework, please mark it as such by adding the tag `homework` to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
while c:
    do_stuff()
    c = raw_input('Do you want to contine y/n')
    if c.lower().startswith('y'):
        c = True
    else:
        c = False
```

Comment: `c = c.lower().startswith('y')`?

Comment: @Daenyth `Y`, `Yes`, `Yeahhh!!!`, `Yippie-ya-yo`, `Yet another possible answer`... or something.